# Android : Getting Thumbnail Info from an Image

Tags: android, image-manipulation

How do i get image thumbnail from the given file path? Here what i am doing

```
    Intent cameraIntent = new Intent("android.media.action.IMAGE_CAPTURE");
    startActivityForResult(cameraIntent, CAMERA_PIC_REQUEST);
```

On "onActivityResult", i get the image in Intent data.

I want to extract thumbnail info from this image. How do i extract it, so that i can show that thumbnail as preview

Answer (score 2):

Once you have the bitmap, you can convert it to a thumbnail 
using [createScaledBitmap (Bitmap src, int dstWidth, int dstHeight, boolean filter)](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/graphics/Bitmap.html#createScaledBitmap%28android.graphics.Bitmap,%20int,%20int,%20boolean%29) or, for Android2.2 and up, 
using [Bitmap extractThumbnail (Bitmap source, int width, int height)](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/media/ThumbnailUtils.html#extractThumbnail%28android.graphics.Bitmap,%20int,%20int,%20int%29).

Answer (score 1):

Check out the thumbnail generation routines for media provider:
http://developer.android.com/reference/android/media/ThumbnailUtils.html

```
Bitmap thumbBitmap = ThumbnailUtils.extractThumbnail(BitmapFactory.decodeFile(filePath), thumbWidth, thumbHeight);
```

Comment: make sure to use a "option" parameter. Or it may result in OOM errors.Eg:MediaStore.Video.Thumbnails.MINI_KIND

Answer (score 0):

I think you'll have to get the full image and either scale it, or decode it specifying inSampleSize>1 in BitmapFactory.Options.

Answer (score 0):

Check out the thumbnail generation class inside Android itself - http://developer.android.com/reference/android/media/ThumbnailUtils.html

It's available since API level 8.